# Fit double logistic function to a time series

Tags: r, time-series, non-linear-regression

For the following time series data:

#1. dates of 15 day frequency:

```
dates = seq(as.Date("2016-09-01"), as.Date("2020-07-30"), by=15) #96 times observation
```

#2. water content in crops corresponding to the times given.

```
water <- c(0.5702722, 0.5631781, 0.5560839, 0.5555985, 0.5519783, 0.5463459, 
0.5511598, 0.546652, 0.5361545, 0.530012, 0.5360571, 0.5396569, 
0.5683526, 0.6031535, 0.6417821, 0.671358, 0.7015542, 0.7177007, 
0.7103561, 0.7036985, 0.6958607, 0.6775161, 0.6545367, 0.6380155, 
0.6113306, 0.5846186, 0.5561815, 0.5251135, 0.5085149, 0.495352, 
0.485819, 0.4730029, 0.4686458, 0.4616468, 0.4613918, 0.4615532, 
0.4827496, 0.5149105, 0.5447824, 0.5776764, 0.6090217, 0.6297454, 
0.6399422, 0.6428941, 0.6586344, 0.6507473, 0.6290631, 0.6011123, 
0.5744375, 0.5313527, 0.5008027, 0.4770338, 0.4564025, 0.4464508, 
0.4309046, 0.4351668, 0.4490393, 0.4701232, 0.4911582, 0.5162941, 
0.5490387, 0.5737573, 0.6031149, 0.6400073, 0.6770058, 0.7048311, 
0.7255012, 0.739107, 0.7338938, 0.7265202, 0.6940718, 0.6757214, 
0.6460862, 0.6163091, 0.5743775, 0.5450822, 0.5057753, 0.4715266, 
0.4469859, 0.4303232, 0.4187793, 0.4119401, 0.4201316, 0.426369, 
0.4419331, 0.4757525, 0.5070846, 0.5248457, 0.5607567, 0.5859825, 
0.6107531, 0.6201754, 0.6356589, 0.6336177, 0.6275579, 0.6214981)
```

I want to fit a double-logistic function curve to the data.
I found some examples and packages that can be of help,

https://greenbrown.r-forge.r-project.org/man/FitDoubleLogElmore.html
and an example here - [Indexes overlap error when using dplyr to run a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73295408/indexes-overlap-error-when-using-dplyr-to-run-a-function).

However, the examples given only consider annual time series.
I have tried to fit the function as:

```
x <- ts(water, start = c(2016,17), end = c(2020, 16), frequency = 24)
smooth.water = FitDoubleLogBeck(x, weighting = T, hessian = F, plot = T, ninit = 10)
plot(water)
plot(smooth.water$predicted)
plot(water- smooth.water$predicted)
```

However, this function does not seem to fit the entire time series. How can I run the function to fit the entire time series? Also, I noticed the output is different at different run, and I am not sure what makes that happen.

Answer (score 1):

`FitDoubleLogBeck` can deal only with 1-year data, so you need analyze the data year by year. To do it  just take `window` for 1 year then fit the data separately for each year.

As for different results at different runs the algorithm randomly chooses the initial parameters. The graph of double logistic curve is bell shaped. However you applying the algorithm to "sine"-like data but the algorithm expects to have "bell". Then it treats the `water` data as a cloud of points so the results are meaningless and very sensetive to intial parameter setting.

Code:

```
set.seed(123)
par(mfrow = c(1, 3))
# water vector taken from question above
x <- ts(water, start = c(2016,17), end = c(2020, 16), frequency = 24)

res <- sapply((2017:2019), function(year) { 
  x2 <- as.vector(window(x, start=c(year, 1), end=c(year, 24)))
  smooth.water2 = FitDoubleLogBeck(x2, weighting = T, hessian = F, plot = T, ninit = 10)
  title(main = year)
  c(year = year, smooth.water2$params)
})

t(res)
```

Output:

[image]

```
     year         mn          mx       sos        rsp       eos        rau
[1,] 2017 -0.7709318  0.17234293 16.324163 -0.6133117  6.750885 -0.7618376
[2,] 2018 -0.8900971  0.09398673  7.529345  0.6701200 17.319465  0.8277409
[3,] 2019 -4.7669470 -0.34648434 15.930455 -0.2570877 10.690043 -0.2267284
```

Comment: @Atem: Thank you for helping out. How can I save the outputs of the model? I want to merge and save fitted model values for the entire time series, and compute difference between the model fitted values and original values.

Comment: You can use formula from here https://github.com/cran/phenopix/blob/master/R/FitDoubleLogBeck.R: xpred <- mn + (mx - mn) * (1/(1+exp(-rsp * (t - sos))) + 1/(1+exp(rau * (t - eos)))). Just put coefficents obtained above.